# Accessing virtual attribute from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

I have experimented, without success, with trying to access a virtual attribute in a model from a JSON call. Let's say I have the following models and controller code

```
class Product
 name,
 description,
 price,
 attr_accessor :discounted_price 
end

class Price
 discount
end

class ProductsController
 def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render :json => @product }                                     
  end
 end
end
```

What I like is to have the JSON output also include Product.discounted_price which is calculated in real-time for each call, ie discounted_price = Price.discount * Product.price. Is there a way to accomplish this?

**SOLUTION:**
With the initial help from dmarkow, I figured it out, my actual scenario is more complex than the above example. I can do something like this, in the Product model, add a getter method

```
def discounted_price
 ...# do the calculation here
end
```

In the JSON call do this

```
store = Store.find(1)
store.as_json(:include => :products, :methods => :discounted_price)
```

Comment: Why do you have price as another class?

Comment: Ok, bad example but for the sake of discussion, let's assume that I need to do that :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can run `to_json` with a `:methods` parameter to include the result of those method(s).

```
render :json => @product.to_json(:methods => :discounted_price)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but my actual scenario is more complicated. Let's say product belongs to store and store has many products. I need to return json with @store.to_json(:include => :products) and be able to set the product.discounted_price during the call. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I can do something like this, in the Product model, add a method
def discounted_price
 ...# do the calculation here
end

In the JSON call do this 
store = Store.find(1)
store.as_json(:include => products, :methods => :discounted_price)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the gem RABL, as shown in this railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl?view=asciicast

RABL gives you fine grained control of the json you produce, including collections and children.